# runtime "mfp" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted.: HTTP 404 - Not Found

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Good Day!

I have run simple Cordova Mobile App - ResourceRequestCordova from Github, and I have using example JavaAdapter, some problem while submit my form. But the problem is , its shown

Errors: runtime "mfp" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted.: HTTP 404 - Not Found

.. I'm Using new MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 Dev Kit.

1) My Cordova Code index.js:

```
submitRequest:function() {
    var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var middle = document.getElementById("middle").value;
    var last = document.getElementById("last").value;
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var birthdate = document.getElementById("birthdate").value;
    var height = document.getElementById("height").value;

    //JavaAdapter expects first, middle and last to be part of the POST URL path.
    var url = "/adapters/javaAdapter/users/"+first+"/"+middle+"/"+last;
    var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(url, WLResourceRequest.POST);

    //JavaAdapter expects age to be a query parameter.
    resourceRequest.setQueryParameter("age", age);

    //JavaAdapter expects birthdate to be a header parameter.
    resourceRequest.setHeader("birthdate",birthdate);

    //JavaAdapter expects height to be a form parameter.
    var formParameters = {};
    formParameters.height = height;

    resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParameters).then(app.onSuccess, app.onFailure);
    window.plugins.spinnerDialog.show(null,null,function(){/*no callback - force the use of SpinnerDialog.hide() */ });
},
```

Errors

```
Errors:
{ getAdapterError: FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found. : FWLSE3038E: The adapter "javaAdapter" of the runtime "mfp" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted.: HTTP 404 - Not Found
   at _processResponse (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\mdo-server-support\lib\rest-client-api\adapter.js:550:23)
   at C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\mdo-server-support\lib\rest-client-api\adapter.js:464:22
   at _fulfilled (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
   at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
   at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
   at C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
   at runSingle (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
   at flush (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
   at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
   at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
 jse_shortmsg: 'FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found. : FWLSE3038E: The adapter "javaAdapter" of the runtime "mfp" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted.',
 jse_summary: 'FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found. : FWLSE3038E: The adapter "javaAdapter" of the runtime "mfp" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted.: HTTP 404 - Not Found',
 jse_cause: 
  { NotFound: HTTP 404 - Not Found
      at FormData.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mfpdev-cli\node_modules\mdo-server-support\lib\rest-client\get.js:93:25)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:474:21)
      at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:99:23)
      at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:363:20)
      at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10) name: 'NotFound' },
```

Comment: Have you got any solution to above problem?

Comment: yep, i got it, first just build the adapter program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> FWLSE3038E: The adapter "javaAdapter" of the runtime "mfp" does not exist in the MobileFirst administration database. The database may be corrupted.'

It sounds like you did not properly build and deploy your adapter.

After you build and deploy the adapter, load the MobileFirst Console and verify that the adapter exists in the list of adapters.